# Google cloud platform send quota increase request using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I need to automate sending quota increase request to GCP support for each new project. Is there a wasy to send quota increase request using API? Thuis is how it looks in web ui: [image]

Comment: I wrote an article where I use the quota API. It could be a starting point for you. https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-preserve-your-innovation-speed-and-your-budget-with-quotas-apis-d20557d191ab

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit? You want to increase Dialogflow quota using API, only for new projects? Or you want to configure each new project to have higher quota? How many new project would you have each week?

Comment: I need to create a GCP project and an agent in it, which I can acheve by API, then I need to increase a quota for that project. I do not have info about numbers of projects, but if there is a way to automate quotas, I would like to do so, if not, then this is going to be manual. So far I only see API to reduce qutas.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure if this is possible. When I tried to use value higher than default (300) I've always got error `"reason": "COMMON_QUOTA_CONSUMER_OVERRIDE_TOO_HIGH"` I will try some different approach and let you know in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

I've run various scenarios but I was not able to increase this limit using the API. Default Quota values can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#table). Under `ES Agent`, in example for `Agent Assist analyze text/audio operations` you have a default quota `300 requests per minute`.

When you are requesting an increased limit for the first time using `UI`, there is `Request Description`. This description is sent to your service provider, analyzed and evaluated and then approved or rejected.

[image]

I don't think the API affords a justification at the moment as this mechanism creates a support case for the quota increase request and is handled by support. If you would use it, you will get error response:

> "reason": "COMMON_QUOTA_CONSUMER_OVERRIDE_TOO_HIGH"

Quota increase must be approved by support, thus API is not able to set additional quota.

Answering to your question:

> Is there a wasy to send quota increase request using API?

I don't think it's possible for new projects as actions from `service provider` are required. For additional quota, the GCP user must submit through the UI.

Just as addition, `guillaume blaquiere` mentioned in his [great guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-preserve-your-innovation-speed-and-your-budget-with-quotas-apis-d20557d191ab) (in my opinion) how to change quotas (within quota limits) using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/). It looks like this:

```
provider "google" {
    project = "<PrjoectName>"
    region = "us-central"
}

resource "google_service_usage_consumer_quota_override" "override" {
    provider = google-beta
    project = "<ProjectName>"
    service = "dialogflow.googleapis.com"
    metric = "dialogflow.googleapis.com%2FAnalyzeContentOperations"
    limit = "%2Fmin%2Fproject"
    override_value = "250"
    force = true
}
```

Comment: I wish I read it before spending a few hours to figure out which metric should I use from.